# dynamic template system which autoloads from HTML (minimal PHP)

Tags: php, html, templates, model-view-controller

I already have a templating engine that I wrote and use, but am wanting to go for something better and I want to know if what I'm planning to write already exists or not, because I have VERY specific wants for this.

**My Question:** Does a templating system with the features I describe below already exist?
**If not**, are there any libraries that allow SOME of the features which I could possibly integrate with eachother and integrate into some of my own code, so I only have to write some of the stuff?

I believe the answer to be **no**, but I figured I'd ask before spending many many hours making it myself.

My intention is to integrate PHP,HTML,CSS, and JS into a single object oriented system all of which interact cleanly with one another.  I already wrote a javascript class system which I would integrate to accomplish that, given that I've already established everything I describe below.

**TLDR;** 
In short, I'm looking for an object oriented templating engine that autoloads html, css, javascript, and php files without having any special syntax or new languages to write in. Plus, I would like it to be able to use HTML files to build PHP objects based on paramaters in the file.

What I'm wanting:
**Autoloading**. For example, given template.html:

```
    <div class="templateEngine Content">
         <div class="templateEngine Content-Head"></div>
         <div class="templateEngine Content-Body"></div>
         <div class="stylizedClass">
             static content
         </div>
    </div>
```

It should load the PHP class `Content` and associated resource files (such as `MySite/Content/Content.[extension]` and call some `loader` method automatically.

Then it would also load up `Content-Head` (PHP class `\Content\Head` w/ the namespace) which would be found at `MySite/Content/Head/Head.[extension]` and `Content-Body`, but it would skip `stylizedClass`

Furthermore, when each of the classes (`Content`, `Content-Head`, `Content-Body`) load, they would check for associated `html` templates and load those where the PHP file does not have the loader method

To explain that, you would be able to load the `Content-Head` with either the following PHP file OR html file.
`/Site/Content/Head/Head.php`:

```
namespace Content;

class Content {
    /** returns the inner html
    */
    public function innerHtml(){
        return MyDBSystem::loadItem(SOME_ID)->content;
    }
}
```

and
`/Site/Content/Content/Head.html`:

```
<div class="somethingStatic">
   some stupid static content
</div>
<div class="templateEngine Content-Head-CrazyLoader"></div>
```

So, if the php file/class and method exists, it would call the `innerHtml()` method. If the php file does not exist, then it would run `Head.html`, autoloading the `Content-Head-CrazyLoader` class (oh, yeah. I also want it to support nesting like a boss).

**To summarize**, `Template.html` would be loaded, auto loading `Content-Head` and inserting the return value of `\Content\Head::innerHtml()` or the content of the `/Site/Content/Head/Head.html`into the `<div>` which has class `Content-Head`.

**HTML to PHP object mapping:**
This, I think, seems a bit more straightforward.

For a file `/Site/AutoMap/AutoMap.edit.html`:

```
<div class="templateEngine Cool-AutoMap">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="CoolName"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="isFunny" checked>
    <select name="multi">
        <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

the PHP file `/Site/AutoMap/AutoMap.php` would be generated like:

```
<?php
    namespace Cool;

    class AutoMap {

        public $name;
        public $isFunny;

        public $multi;
        public $multiOptions;

        public function __constructed(){
            //theoretically, the template engine would first declare 
            //  this->propName = new \TemplateEngine\Prop\DataType();
            //  for each prop
            $this->name->value = 'CoolName';
            $this->isFunny->value = TRUE;
            $this->multi->value = 'cat';

            $this->multi->options = array("cat"=>'Cat',"dog"=>'Dog');
        }

    }
?>
```

**Pre-compiler:**
Essentially, it would build cached PHP pages with dynamic sections in them for performance, so the stuff that's static really is static and so that the dynamic stuff doesn't have to run through the crazy autoloading on every page request.

**Also:**

- In HTML files, you would be able to include dynamic bits like: `<?=time()?>` for where you just have a simple need for some PHP.
- There would also be a database abstraction layer, but I already wrote that myself and would integrate it with the rest of the system to auto-load database objects

Comment: I realize it's possible some may say this is too broad or off-topic, but I disagree, since I am looking for a library matching my specific needs, and I am not looking for opinions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to exist. All the options I have seen require PHP code or their own simple custom language to operate. And they don't seem to autoload anything. Ie, you have to create all your variables in PHP, and write PHP code to load up the template.

I wrote my own (mostly, still in progress) and I'll probably open source it (parts of it, anyway) as I see fit, but probably not for a few months.